# How to get param values from deeplinks

Tags: javascript, react-native

I open my app with a deeplink

```
myscheme://?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

How can I get the value of the parameters? I found different posts that treat this subject but the once I tried works on http links I think, I alwayse get a warning telling me that BlobURL object is not supported yet.

```
var url = new URL(data);
alert(url.searchParams.get("param1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your example, and it works, with slight adjustment:

```
let myscheme = 'http://www.example.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2'
var url = new URL(myscheme);
alert(url.searchParams.get("param1"));
```

More details can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

Comment: new URL(myscheme); is causing the problem for me. Do you import URL from somewhere?

Comment: I do not. It works just like that in Chrome (Mac) Console.

Comment: Ah ok, but not in react-native apps

Comment: new URL(myscheme) will work even inside react-native. Your problem is the myscheme.

Comment: Ran into the same problem using React Native. This solution worked when importing URL from react-native-url-polyfill: 


```
import { URL } from 'react-native-url-polyfill';
```